# Как передать ссылку на файл через переменную в атрибут src тэга img в куске html кода на Python?

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, format, qlabel

Я пишу программу на *Python* и столкнулся с такой проблемой: 
мне необходимо передать путь файла в код **`html`** через переменную.

Как это можно сделать?

```
pngвdir = 'book.png';
label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
    "<img src='pngdir' width=250><hr width=200 style='margin: 15px 0'>"
)
```

Т.е., есть переменная `pngdir`, в ней находится путь к файлу и её как-то нужно запихнуть в код **`html`**. Делаю я это для того, что бы при компоновке *PyInstaller* смог найти эту картинку. К слову, путь будет изменён.

Это будет выглядит уже так:

```
if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
    pngdir = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'book.png')
else:
    pngdir = 'book.png'
label = QtWidgets.QLabel("<img src='pngdir' width=250><hr width=200 style='margin: 15px 0'>");
```

Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys                             
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        pngdir = 'Ok.png';
        label = QLabel("<img src={} width=250><hr width=200 style='margin: 15px 0'>"
                       "".format(pngdir));  

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!